# Fragment data is going null when another fragment loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

In `NavigationDrawer` I am taking two Fragments. In each Fragment I have tab sliders. When I am clicking for the first time data is coming in both fragments but when I am going from one fragment to another data is null in both of the fragments. I have checked for the saving state of fragments but still the problem is not solved. Any idea how we can resolve this issue?

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
if (navigationView != null) {
    setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new LoginFragment()).commit();
}
```

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            System.out.println("Navigation Drawer Item Clciked ---->" + navDrawerClickedItem);
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.roof:
                    if (navDrawerClickedItem == menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                        System.out.println("New roof Fragment already loaded");
                    } else {
                        navDrawerClickedItem = menuItem.getItemId();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new RoofTabFragment()).commit();
                        System.out.println("New roof Fragment Created");
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.floor:
                    if (navDrawerClickedItem == menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                        System.out.println("Floor Fragment already loaded");
                    } else {
                        navDrawerClickedItem = menuItem.getItemId();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new FloorTabFragment()).commit();
                        System.out.println("Floor Fragment Created");
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.signOut:
                    LogMeOut();
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding logcat with the exception?

Comment: try creating a singleton fragment ? :D

Comment: @darthvading not getting any exception

Comment: because everytime you are creating new instance of fragment  while replacing e.g: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new RoofTabFragment())...so saving state of fragment won't work.Create a instance variable fragment...add that to backstack with appropriate tags and extract those fragments from backstack

Comment: @ShadowDroid ! Is this the correct way ?
if (fragment != null) {
                            System.out.println("not null");
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = 

getSupportFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .add(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack("")
                                    .remove(fragment)
                                    .commit();
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved  by replacing `getFragmentManager(`) to `getChildFragmentManager()` in `viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have Faced such problem in past in such cases what i do is make a static field in may be **Main Activity** or **First Activity** and get all the data there and give it **setter** and **getter** methods and the data will be static and it will be accessible throught the app and the data won't change

and this way your data will be common with all your **Fragments** and Preloaded as well and data will be singleton as well